# Javascript changes on window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize, scroll

I am trying to make my javascript change when the window resizes, but cannot seem to get it to work. The only difference I would like is for the offset().top to change from -90 to -60 as the window becomes smaller than 768px.

This is what I have so far:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top-90
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 768){  
        $(function() {
          $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
              var target = $(this.hash);
              target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
              if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                  scrollTop: target.offset().top-60
                }, 1000);
                return false;
              }
            }
          });
        });
    }   
});
```

Any advice would be really great!

Thank you

Comment: Please provide jsFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first click event handler `$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click` is binded everytime the js is run.

On resize you attach a second handler to click event - it is NOT overwritting the first one - so there are two event handlers attached for one event. 
I guess you want first do sth like `$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').off('click');` to unbind first event handler on window resize and then attach the second one.

But since you are changing only one small piece of code you'd rather write:

```
    $(function() {   $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top - ( ($(window).width() <= 768) ? 60 : 90)
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }
        }   
        }); 
    });
```

Note the scrollTop line